# Web2py Access Control for multi-tenant system

Tags: python, web2py, access-control

I am developing a website which will be used as a multi-tenant system. It will be used by the members of multiple organization. The pages in the system could be different for different organization. I want tos use web2py inbuilt access control system. However I am not able to figure out how do I differentiate users as per the tenants. I cannot mention tenant in auth_user as a single user may have access to multiple tenants(in case of super admin). I also cannot mention it in auth_group table for the same reason. What I think is that I can do it in auth_permission table by mentioning tenant in the name field of that table. Will it be a correct approach? Please suggest me if you have any solution to this.

Comment: Have you considered the built-in [multi-tenancy functionality](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Common-fields-and-multi-tenancy)?

Comment: Thnks for sharing this. I think it is very useful. But in our case we are not going to use **request.env.http_host** as our default tenant. We have a table where we have this tenant information. These could be different from host. We want to use tenant_id(primary key of tenant table) as request_tenant common field. How can we do it? Even if we can do that how is it going to filter records automatically depending on tenant_id?

Comment: When a request comes into your application, how will you know to which tenant it belongs?